# FormDataRoutingRedirect exception from a URL without trainling slash

Tags: python, url, flask, python-2.6

I'm doing an ajax POST request and I'm getting this exception:

```
[Fri Nov 29 20:48:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.25.100]     self.raise_routing_exception(req)
[Fri Nov 29 20:48:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.25.100]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1439, in raise_routing_exception
[Fri Nov 29 20:48:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.25.100]     raise FormDataRoutingRedirect(request)
[Fri Nov 29 20:48:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.25.100] FormDataRoutingRedirect: A request was sent to this URL (http://example.com/myurl) but a redirect was issued automatically by the routing system to "http://example.com/myurl/".  The URL was defined with a trailing slash so Flask will automatically redirect to the URL with the trailing slash if it was accessed without one.  Make sure to directly send your POST-request to this URL since we can't make browsers or HTTP clients redirect with form data reliably or without user interaction.
```

The route definition is this:

```
@app.route('/myurl')
def my_func():
```

I can see in Firebug that the request is sent without the trailing slash:

```
http://example.com/myurl
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

I have this in another module:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<a>/')
@app.route('/<a>/<b>')
def index(a='', b=''):
```

Could this last one be getting in the way? Or what? Flask version is 0.10.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that your `/myurl` route is not defined to accept `POST` requests, and your `/<a>/` route is, so Werkzeug picks `/<a>/`.

The behavior for routes that end in a slash is explained [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#rule-format). By default invoking a route defined with a trailing slash without that slash triggers a redirect to the trailing slash version of the URL. This of course does not work well for `POST` requests, so you get the `FormDataRoutingRedirect` exception.

I suspect if you send your `POST` request to `/myurl/` then your `/<a>/` route will be invoked just fine, though clearly this is not what you want.

What I think you are missing is accepting `POST` requests on `/myurl`, which you can do as follows:

```
@app.route('/myurl', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def my_func():
```

Comment: _My guess is that your /myurl route is not defined to accept `POST` requests, and your /<a>/ route is_. Neither were defined to accept `POST` or any other method but when I added the `POST` method to `/myurl` it worked.

Comment: Ah, okay. So the redirect form error occurs before Flask decided that there is no match for your request type.